# Ul li style-type:decimal is not working in IE7?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

While using style-type:decimal in ul li, the IE7 browser takes up to 9 numbers, after that it start with 0 not 10. What is the solution for this problem?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow Jay. May i suggest you adding the code you have so far to display what you tried and what you think is wrong? A single line of text makes it hard for people to answer your question. It may also help if you add the end result you wish to accomplish, there is a good chance there is a better way to do things.

Answer (score 1):

ul means 'unordered list'
ol means 'ordered list'

OL is what you try to achieve. So change your ul-Tag to ol:

```
<ol>
    <li>test</li>
</ol>
```

See here: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GkBpA/1/)

Take care with css-resets. Some will overwrite the ol list-style.

Answer (score 0):

The property name is `list-style-type`, but I suppose that’s what you have, if you get numbers and not bullets for a `ul` in the first place.

The numbers are probably truncated on the left, because there is not enough room for more than one digit on the left of the item contents. This depends on the left margin and left padding of the `ul` and `li` elements (in a browser-dependent manner), so you have probably set them in CSS, and you now have to modify those settings to allow more room.